# Python: Referencing a column in DataFrame using a function

Tags: python, dataframe, dynamic-columns

This is the code that I have:

```
.......

gender = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)]["gender"].tolist()[0]
cell = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)]["cell"].tolist()[0]
bloodtype = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)]["bloodType"].tolist()[0]

expList = tempPos[(tempPos.gender == gender) & (tempPos.cell == cell) & (tempPos.bloodType == bloodtype)]

.......
```

Now there are several other columns that can be referenced in the tempPos dataframe (in the above example I am using gender, cell & bloodType)

Is there a way I can define a function and reference the columns dynamically?

```
def generateProbability(col1, col2, col3):
    .......
    col1val = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)][col1].tolist()[0]
    col2val = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)][col2].tolist()[0]
    col3val = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)][col3].tolist()[0]
    expList = tempPos[(tempPos.col1 == col1val) & (tempPos.col2 == col2val) & (tempPos.col3 == col3val)]
    ........

generateProbability("Age","Gender","bloodType")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not change `data.loc[np.where(data['ID'] == id)]["cell"]` to `data.loc[data['ID'] == id, "cell"]`?

Answer (score 0):

You needn't create a function. You could just access them through a `for` loop.

```
column_outputs = dict    # Dictionary to hold column outputs.

for column in data.columns:
    column_outputs[column] = data.loc[data['ID'] == id, column].tolist()[0]
```

`column_outputs` should now contain the desired values for each column, which you can access using the column name as a key.

Comment: My bad, the following code has no issues:     col1val = data.loc[np.where(data['ID']==id)][col1].tolist()[0]
The part I need help is here - expList = tempPos[(tempPos.col1 == col1val), since tempPos.col1 does not exist -- reference needs to be dynamic